# Extraction of tuned hyperparameters from tuning instance archive

Tags: mlr3

I've build an automated machine learning system based on the following example:

https://mlr-org.com/gallery/2021-03-11-practical-tuning-series-build-an-automated-machine-learning-system/

I've used the learners xgboost and Random Forest and made use of `branching`. xgboost gave me the best results during the training phase. Therefore I've extracted the optimized hyperparameters and build the final xgboost model:

```
lrn = as_learner(graph)
lrn$param_set$values = instance$result_learner_param_vals
```

I'm also interested in the `param_vals` of the best performing Random Forest model.

I've thought, I could get the hyperparameters and save the best Random Forest model like that:

```
Arch = as.data.table(instance$archive, exclude_columns = NULL) # so we keep the uhash
best_RF = Arch[branch.selection == "lrn_ranger"]
best_RF = best_RF[which.min(best_RF$regr.rmse), ] # to get the best RF model from the data table
instance$archive$learner_param_vals(uhash = best_RF$uhash)

lrn_2 = as_learner(graph)
lrn_2$param_set$values = instance$archive$learner_param_vals(uhash = best_RF$uhash)
#lrn_2$param_set$values = instance$archive$learner_param_vals(i = best_RF$batch_nr)
```

When I use the `uhash` or the `batch_nr` I can't retrieve the hyperparameters of the best Random Forest model. I always receive the `param_set` of the first row in the archive, while the `uhash` and `batch_nr` are correct:

```
$slct_1.selector
selector_name(c("T", "RH"))

$missind.which
[1] "missing_train"

$missind.type
[1] "factor"

$missind.affect_columns
selector_invert(selector_type(c("factor", "ordered", "character")))

$encode.method
[1] "treatment"

$encode.affect_columns
selector_type("factor")

$branch.selection
[1] "lrn_ranger"

$slct_2.selector
selector_name(c("T"))

$mutate.mutation
$mutate.mutation$Tra.Trafo
~(T^(2))/(2)


$mutate.delete_originals
[1] FALSE

$xgboost.nthread
[1] 1

$xgboost.verbose
[1] 0

$ranger.min.node.size
[1] 15

$ranger.mtry
[1] 1

$ranger.num.threads
[1] 1

$ranger.num.trees
[1] 26

$ranger.sample.fraction
[1] 0.8735846
```

Can somebody give me a hint about how I can reach my goal of the extraction of other hyperparameters, when I'm not only interested in the output of `instance$result_learner_param_vals`?

**Edit:**

I wanted to clarify something, which is also related to branching. I'm not sure if it is intended to work like that after reading the comment of @be_marc. Let's use the gallery example I've posted as a reference. I want to compare the results of different tuned branches using a GraphLearner object. I've created the final model like in the gallery example, which is in my case a xgboost model. I also want to create the final models for the other branches for benchmarking purposes. The issue is, that if I don't create a `deep clone` of the original `graph_learner`, the original graph_learner gets his value changed for the parameter `branch.selection`. Why can't I just use a normal clone? Why must it be a deep clone? Is it supposed to work like that? Mostlikely I'm not sure what the difference is between a clone and deep clone.

```
# Reference for cloning https://mlr3.mlr-org.com/reference/Resampling.html
# equivalent to object called graph_learner in mlr3 gallery example 
graph_learner$param_set$values$branch.selection # original graph_learner object (reference MLR_gallery in first post)

# individually uncomment for different cases
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#MLR_graph = graph # object graph_learner doesn't keeps its original state
#MLR_graph = graph$clone() # object graph_learner doesn't keeps its original state
MLR_graph = graph$clone(deep = TRUE) # object graph_learner keeps its original state
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
MLR_graph$param_set$values$branch.selection # value inherited from original graph
MLR_graph$param_set$values$branch.selection = "lrn_MLR" # change set value to other branch
MLR_graph$param_set$values$branch.selection # changed to branch "lrn_MLR"
MLR_lrn = as_learner(MLR_graph) # create a learner from graph with new set branch

# Here we can see the different behaviours based on if we don't clone, clone or deep clone
# at the end, the original graph_learner is supposed to keep it's original state
graph_learner$param_set$values$branch.selection
MLR_lrn$param_set$values$branch.selection
```

When I don't use a deep clone, the overall best model `lrn` (jump to the beginning of this post) gets affected too. In my case, it was xgboost. The parameter `branch.selection` of `lrn` gets set to `lrn_MLR`:

```
print(lrn)

<GraphLearner:slct_1.copy.missind.imputer_num.encode.featureunion.branch.nop_1.nop_2.slct_2.nop_3.nop_4.mutate.xgboost.ranger.MLR.unbranch>
* Model: list
* Parameters: slct_1.selector=<Selector>, missind.which=missing_train, missind.type=factor,
  missind.affect_columns=<Selector>, encode.method=treatment, encode.affect_columns=<Selector>,
  branch.selection=lrn_MLR, slct_2.selector=<Selector>, mutate.mutation=<list>, mutate.delete_originals=FALSE,
  xgboost.alpha=1.891, xgboost.eta=0.06144, xgboost.lambda=0.01341, xgboost.max_depth=3, xgboost.nrounds=122,
  xgboost.nthread=1, xgboost.verbose=0, ranger.num.threads=1
* Packages: mlr3, mlr3pipelines, stats, mlr3learners, xgboost, ranger
* Predict Types:  [response], se, distr
* Feature Types: logical, integer, numeric, character, factor, ordered, POSIXct
* Properties: featureless, hotstart_backward, hotstart_forward, importance, loglik, missings, oob_error,
  selected_features, weights
```

**Edit 2:**
Okay, I just found out, that I should always use deep clones, when I work with different, distinct learners in an experiment: https://github.com/mlr-org/mlr3/issues/344

The behaviour is intended.

Comment: You found a bug. I will get back to you when the problem is solved. Link to [issue](https://github.com/mlr-org/mlr3/issues/854).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We fixed the bug in the latest dev version (10.09.2022). You can install it with

```r
remotes::install_github("mlr-org/mlr3")
```

The learners were not reassembled properly. This works again

```r
library(mlr3pipelines)
library(mlr3tuning)

learner = po("subsample") %>>% lrn("classif.rpart", cp = to_tune(0.1, 1))

# hyperparameter tuning on the pima indians diabetes data set
instance = tune(
  method = "random_search",
  task = tsk("pima"),
  learner = learner,
  resampling = rsmp("cv", folds = 3),
  measure = msr("classif.ce"),
  term_evals = 10
)

instance$archive$learner_param_vals(i = 1)
instance$archive$learner_param_vals(i = 2)
```